# Python3 json lib loads json lost data

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

Got a wired problem when load a JSON object from a file, the JSON object is:

```
{"log":"{\"log\":\"[          ] 5% db.btree\\r[=         ] 10% db.btree\\r[=         ] 15% db.btree\\r[==        ] 20% db.btree\\r[==        ] 25% db.btree\\r[===       ] 30% db.btree\\r[===       ] 35% db.btree\\r[====      ] 40% db.btree\\r[====      ] 45% db.btree\\r[=====     ] 50% db.btree\\r[=====     ] 55% db.btree\\r[======    ] 60% db.btree\\r[======    ] 65% db.btree\\r[=======   ] 70% db.btree\\r[=======   ] 75% db.btree\\r[========  ] 80% db.btree\\r[========  ] 85% db.btree\\r[========= ] 90% db.btree\\r[========= ] 95% db.btree\\r[==========] 100% db.btree\\rff 00000000               . end of MapIt for_write is 0 - map-style 0 append_fd is -1\\n\",\"stream\":\"stderr\",\"time\":\"2019-02-26T20:54:40.335910928Z\"}","pod_name":"xxx-xxx-0","namespace_name":"default","host":"ip-11-0-194-0.us-west-1.compute.internal","container_name":"xxx"}
```

After load the JSON object with log_content = json.loads(input), the json object looks good.

```
'log': '[          ] 5% db.btree\r[=         ] 10% db.btree\r[=         ] 15% db.btree\r[==        ] 20% db.btree\r[==        ] 25% db.btree\r[===       ] 30% db.btree\r[===       ] 35% db.btree\r[====      ] 40% db.btree\r[====      ] 45% db.btree\r[=====     ] 50% db.btree\r[=====     ] 55% db.btree\r[======    ] 60% db.btree\r[======    ] 65% db.btree\r[=======   ] 70% db.btree\r[=======   ] 75% db.btree\r[========  ] 80% db.btree\r[========  ] 85% db.btree\r[========= ] 90% db.btree\r[========= ] 95% db.btree\r[==========] 100% db.btree\rff 00000000               . end of MapIt for_write is 0 - map-style 0 append_fd is -1\n', 'stream': 'stderr', 'time': '2019-02-26T20:54:40.335910928Z'}
```

However, when I print with pretty print, I got

```
{   'log': '[          ] 5% db.btree\r'
       '[=         ] 10% db.btree\r'
       '[=         ] 15% db.btree\r'
       '[==        ] 20% db.btree\r'
       '[==        ] 25% db.btree\r'
       '[===       ] 30% db.btree\r'
       '[===       ] 35% db.btree\r'
       '[====      ] 40% db.btree\r'
       '[====      ] 45% db.btree\r'
       '[=====     ] 50% db.btree\r'
       '[=====     ] 55% db.btree\r'
       '[======    ] 60% db.btree\r'
       '[======    ] 65% db.btree\r'
       '[=======   ] 70% db.btree\r'
       '[=======   ] 75% db.btree\r'
       '[========  ] 80% db.btree\r'
       '[========  ] 85% db.btree\r'
       '[========= ] 90% db.btree\r'
       '[========= ] 95% db.btree\r'
       '[==========] 100% db.btree\r'
       'ff 00000000               . end of MapIt for_write is 0 - '
       'map-style 0 append_fd is -1\n',
'stream': 'stderr',
'time': '2019-02-26T20:54:40.335910928Z'}
```

And when I refer to log_content['log']

```
ff 00000000               . end of MapIt for_write is 0 - map-style 0 append_fd is -1
```

Not sure if it's a bug or I did something wrong? Not look like the'[' and ']' corrupt the JSON data, remove it the problem still exist, Thanks.

Comment: Where do you think you've lost data? It looks to me like all the data is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lost or corrupted data here.

Your pretty-printed output was printed with a tool designed to pretty-print Python data structures, not a JSON serializer. It does not look like valid JSON because it is not supposed to be valid JSON. That output is a valid Python expression that would evaluate to a dict equal to the dict fed to the pretty-printer. (The expression makes use of implicit string literal concatenation to split a string across many lines.)

Your last line was printed with something like `print(log_content['log'])`, which prints the contents of the `log_content['log']` string instead of the string's `repr` representation or some other representation. Your terminal interprets the `\r` characters as an instruction to return the cursor to the beginning of the line (and possibly to clear the line, depending on the details of your terminal). This means that later parts of the output are printed over earlier parts. Looking at what's in the string, it is evident that whatever originally produced that text did this deliberately, to produce a progress bar that updates in place.